# Customise displayed message in Slack from SVN integration

Tags: perl, svn, slack-api, slack

I'm pretty new to [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)). I've created a team, and I've added an integration with our SVN repository. I've set up a "post-commit" script and I get a notification in the intended Slack channel. All is good as far as that goes.

I would like to customise the notification in the slack channel, and I'm failing.

The post-commit script is Perl-based; a number of templates are available. I've used one and added a line to include the files changed thus:

```
my $files = `/usr/bin/svnlook changed -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $date = `/usr/bin/svnlook date -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $log = `/usr/bin/svnlook log -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $who = `/usr/bin/svnlook author -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
chomp $who;

my $payload = {
        'revision'      => $ARGV[1],
        'date'          => $date,
        'author'        => $who,
        'log'           => $log,
        'files'         => $files,
};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(15);

my $req = POST( "https://${opt_domain}/services/hooks/subversion?token=${opt_token}", ['payload' => encode_json($payload)] );
```

The only message I get in the Slack channel is of the form:

```
<rev number>:<author>-<log message>
```

I don't know why I don't get the date and the list of files changed appear in the Slack message. The relevant svnlook commands, when run manually on the server produce the expected results. If I change the relevant bit of the script to:

```
my $payload = {
        'wibble'      => $ARGV[1],
        'date'          => $date,
        'author'        => $who,
        'log'           => $log,
        'files'         => $files,
};
```

and then manually invoke the hook with

```
post-commit /var/svn/repo 5966
```

(for example) I get an output that includes:

```
payload=%7B%22wibble%22%3A%225966%22
```

(as I expected/hoped), but then

```
Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Connection: close
...
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

invalid_payload
```

I was naively expecting the payload to specify the message, so you could craft a message something like:

```
revision: 5696
date: 2016/03/14 12:00:00
author: ...
log: <log text>
files: myfile.c, myfile.h
```

In the above example, I was wondering if I'd get

```
wibble: 5696
```

So, I have to come to the conclusion that something at the Slack end requires only certain fields in the received [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and then formats them into the channel message according to some rule. I have found NO clue what fields are acceptable and how one might exercise some control over the formatting. For example, the fact I don't get an error about an invalid payload suggests that the date and files field names are valid, but how do I get them to appear in the Slack message?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom message you should use [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) in the API. I suspect you are using a Subversion hook, and it probably has a fixed layout of the message.

Post the text you want in the `text` key in the `payload`. That way you can format it as you would a normal Slack message.

Answer (score 0):

Came across wanting to do the same thing. What I ended doing was changing the `$payload`'s log value to include `$files` ... like so:

```
my $files = `/usr/bin/svnlook changed -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $payload = {
    'revision'      => $ARGV[1],
    'url'           => $url,
    'author'        => $who,
    'log'           => "$log\n$files"
};
```

(starting with the sample here: https://github.com/tinyspeck/services-examples/blob/master/subversion.pl)